# trying to add a scroll (overflow-y:hidden;) but it dosent work

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

i have this note i'm working on, i some how blocked the inner div's from coming out of the container div. now i'm trying to add a scroll bar but something is blocking me, i went throw the console log and tried everything i can thing of...

this is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="noteBack.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
        <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="container-box ">
                    <header><span>Note Details</span>
                    </header>
                    <div class="sub-header"><span>Friday 25.7.13 </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-container-box opacity-affect">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10  col-md-offset-0">
                                <div class="dialog-box">
                                    <!--first white box inside the note-->
                                    <div class="dialog-box-circle"></div>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical dialog-vertical-menu"></span>
    <span class="dialog-box-name">Lea Poran -<select>
                    <option>@private</option>       
                    <option>@public</option>        
                   </select>
                   </span>
 <span class="dialog-box-day">2d ago</span>

                                    <div class="dialog-box-text">Don't forget to bring the new calender for the meeting.</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dialog-box">
                            <!--second white box inside the note-->
                            <div class="dialog-box-circle"></div>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical dialog-vertical-menu"></span>
    <span class="dialog-box-name">You -<select>
                    <option>@private</option>       
                    <option>@public</option>        
                   </select>
                   </span>
 <span class="dialog-box-day">2d ago</span>

                            <div class="dialog-box-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque laoreet ex vitae mi venenatis odio felis convallis. Praesent ut consequat orci,</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dialog-box">
                            <!--third white box inside the note-->
                            <div class="dialog-box-circle"></div>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical dialog-vertical-menu"></span>
    <span class="dialog-box-name">You -<select>
                    <option>@private</option>       
                    <option>@public</option>        
                   </select>
                   </span>
 <span class="dialog-box-day">3d ago</span>

                            <div class="dialog-box-text">In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque scelerisque auctor dui. Pellentesque eget eros pretium, sagittis tortor at, tempor turpis.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dialog-box-date">
                            <!--gray box - contains the date--> <span class="dialog-box-date-text">Friday, Apr..Year 2015 Calendar - Time and Date
                </span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="dialog-box">
                            <!--replay of the first white box inside the note-->
                            <div class="dialog-box-circle"></div>   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical dialog-vertical-menu"></span>
    <span class="dialog-box-name">Lea Poran -<select>
                    <option>@private</option>       
                    <option>@public</option>        
                   </select>
                   </span>
 <span class="dialog-box-day">2d ago</span>

                            <div class="dialog-box-text">Don't forget to bring the new calender for the meeting.</div>
                            <div class="button-plus">+
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

this is my css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400, 100, 300, 500, 700, 900);
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400, 300, 700);
 .container-box {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:382px;
    height:529px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
/* .opacity-affect{                 //After button click blur the background

        opacity:0.5;
    }    */
 header {
    /*the red head line*/
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:41px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#de4b4b;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:auto;
}
header span {
    /*text inside the  red head line*/
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:148px;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-bottom:14px;
}
.sub-header {
    /*white sub head line*/
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:37px;
    background-color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    /*change*/
    color:#454545;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    /*change*/
    font-weight:700;
    /*change*/
}
.sub-header span {
    /*text inside the white sub head line*/
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:11px;
    padding-left:24px;
}
.dialog-box {
    /*the white boxes inside the note main*/
    position:relative;
    width:365px;
    background-color:white;
    margin: 8px 0px 10px 8px;
    /*change*/
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    /*change*/
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
    /*change*/
}
.dialog-box-circle {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    border-radius:30px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    margin:15px 8px 14px 15px;
    /*change*/
    vertical-align:middle;
    /*allow text to appear next to the circle div */
}
.dialog-box-name {
    display:inline-block;
    /*change*/
    color:#3eb6d9;
    /*change*/
    font-size:13px;
    margin-top:13px;
    /*change*/
    /* font-weight:bold; */
    font-family:'roboto';
    /*change*/
    font-weight:500;
    /*change*/
}
.dialog-box-text {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#8d8d8d;
    /*change*/
    font-size:13px;
    /*change*/
    font-family:'Roboto';
    /*change*/
    font-weight:400;
    /*change*/
    line-height:17px;
    /*the space between the line*/
    /*change*/
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    margin-top:0px;
    /*change*/
    margin-right:17px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
.dialog-box-name select {
    border:0px;
    font-size:13px;
    /*change*/
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-weight:500;
    color:#454545;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dialog-box-day {
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    /*change*/
    font-family:'Roboto';
    /*change*/
    font-weight:700;
    /*change*/
    margin:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.dialog-vertical-menu {
    float:right;
    margin:8px;
}
.dialog-box-date {
    /*the gray box inside the note main*/
    position:relative;
    width:365px;
    height:37px;
    margin: 0px 8px 10px 8px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
.dialog-box-date-text {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:'Roboto';
    font-weight:500;
    /*change*/
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000000;
    margin-left:14px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.button-plus {
    position:relative;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#f84a4a;
    /* border:1px solid green; */
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    float: right;
    right:8px;
    top:83%;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: you need overflow scroll not hidden. if you want your overflow to scroll

Comment: you need to change **overflow:scroll or auto**. if you use hidden it will hide the overflow content from the div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 times overflow hidden in your css, so ...scroll will be hidden

```
.container-box{     
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:382px;
    height:529px;
    background-color:lightgray;

    overflow:hidden;

    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

try this

```
.container-box{     
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:382px;
    height:529px;
    background-color:lightgray;

    overflow-x:auto;

    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**use this**
**modify your answer**

> **need to change overflow:auto;**

```
.container-box{     
/*position:absolute;*/
width:382px;
height:529px;
background-color:lightgray;
.container-box{     
/*position:absolute;*/
width:382px;
height:529px;
background-color:lightgray;
.container-box{     
/*position:absolute;*/
width:382px;
height:529px;
background-color:lightgray;
overflow:auto;
border:1px solid #cccccc;
margin:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

}

**need example**

> See the **current page of this stack overflow of your pre code**